# how to make a function that prints a variable number of parameters in pascal?

Tags: variables, parameters, numbers, pascal

I want to let the user give me a variable number of strings (as virables). 
example :

begin
cout('Hello').*(' ').*('world')
end.

this will print: "Hello world"
I know I just can let him input a string but I want to this code to work...
I think a record will help nut I dont know how
thank you

Comment: Depending on dialect, search in your manual for "array of const"

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure what is that code example you have written ... but i try to help you.

```
    Program test;
uses crt;

var string1,string2,string3:string;


begin
 write("Write to first string : "); readln(string1);
 write("Write to second string: "); readln(string2);
 write("Write to third string : "); readln(string3);

String2:= string1 +" "+ string3; // it will add first with third string to one with one space

String3:= string2 +" "+ string1;// also 2.+ 1.
clrscr; //clearscreen (in CRT)
writeln("1. = 1.");
writeln("2. = 1. + 3.");
writeln("3. = 2. + 1.");
writeln;
writeln(string1);
writelm(string2);
writeln(string3);
```

I havent tested this (i have written it now for you) i think you will read it and learn how to addict or how to do simple with strings.